# Hibernate in different JVM reading old data

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jvm

I am working on a system where there are multiple programs (each in its own JVM) are doing DB operations.

One component - say A - updates the table entries in MySQL, updating status from 'started' to 'completed', and another daemon - say B - checks the table for all entries that have been marked as 'completed' and performs some operations on them.

The problem is that when A updates the entries at a certain time t1, B is only able to see those changes after either of the following:
 1. when the jvm running B is restarted.
 2. when the thread in B that checks for the changes is stopped for an hour or two. (Basically the thread that checks for entries in 'completed' status repeatedly queries the MySQL table and gets stale data, but during a window stops making any queries. When the window is completed it starts making the same query again and gets the updated data, but between time t1 and the start of the window it always gets stale data)

Comment: try reading up about Hibernate/JPA caching

Comment: There is no L2 cache, and I am not sure whether it is because of transaction isolation since the changes are made in small transactions and by different JVMs

Comment: We are not using HQL but using Criteria for making the query

Comment: Have you checked in the logs whether the necessary SQL statements actually run in A and B? That might help you to judge whether this is a problem of DB transaction isolation or JVM-side caching.

Comment: Verify when both A and B components start and commit their transactions and verify what are their isolation levels. Could you update the question with this information?

Comment: We dont't yet have the SQL statements being fired as its running in INFO mode. I saw here [http://www.coderanch.com/t/415128/ORM/databases/Hibernate-Cache] that default values of cache enable/disable were not being taken. We will probably rerun with the hibernate properties